# Assigning data to the buttons from service Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

I have 4 buttons(Date1, Date2, Time1 and Time2) and 3 labels, i can assign the labels from the given output as

```
_lblName.text = [medicationdicts objectForKey:@"Name"];
_lblMedicine.text = [medicationdicts objectForKey:@"Medicine"];
_lblDate.text = [medicationdicts objectForKey:@"ExpDate"];
```

but, How can i assign the date and time to the buttons like(Date1 = 2017-04-05, Date2 = 2017-04-06, Time1 = 07:00:00 and Time2 = 07:10:00) from following output

```
Name = Abhi;
Medicine = Colpol;
Time =     (
                   {
                       Date = "2017-04-05";
                       Time = "07:00:00";
                   },
                   {
                       Date = "2017-04-06";
                       Time = "07:10:00";
                   }
                   );
ExpDate = "2017-04-30";
```

Help me to solve this issues. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this...

```
    NSArray *times = [medicationdicts objectForKey:@"Time"];

    for (NSDictionary *timeDict in times)
    {
        NSString *time = [timeDict objectForKey:@"Date"];
        NSString *date = [timeDict objectForKey:@"Time"];

        if  ([times indexOfObject:timeDict] == 0)
        {
            [dateButton1 setTitle: date forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [timeButton1 setTitle: time forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [dateButton2 setTitle: date forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [timeButton2 setTitle: time forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title like this:

```
[dateButton setTitle: @"date" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

To get the date

```
medicationdicts[@"Time"][@"Date"];
```

I suggest you parse the JSON to a model that you create e.g `Medication` and use `medication.title`.

Edit: `objectForKey:` works fine as well.